# Extract connected/neighboring regions in an image via a specific input colored pixel

Tags: python, opencv, underline, connected-components, strikethrough

I have an image -
[image]

I would like to get an output image that just has the highlighted red portions.

Output image -
[image]

How would I do this ?

What I am trying to do is isolate underline/strikethrough text decorations so that I can extract the text along with the text decoration information.

What I had in mind -

- Remove all pixels (convert to white) that are not connected to a red
  pixel (connected to red pixel via some other non-white pixel also counts). I tried using connected components but it seems I need to pass
  in a binary image and this approach failed.
- Using a sliding window to iterate through the pixels and if the
  sliding window has a red pixel, don't do anything, if it doesn't,
  turn all the pixel within the window - white. The sliding window size
  will be adjusted based on trial and error.

Comment: Use cv2.inRange() to threshold on the red color. That should make red into white and everything else black. Then findContours or use connected components to extract each region of the image using the mask.

Comment: Check each horizontal line(each row by pixels). If any continuous red pixel, then take that part as underlined